# Joining two tables based on two common columns that appear under different names in each table

Tags: sql

Here is an example of the tables :

**clients**

```
╔══════════╦════════════╗
║ GROUP_ID ║ GROUP_NAME ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ abc      ║ xex        ║
║ def      ║ tet        ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

**teams**

```
╔════════╦════════════╗
║ ACT_ID ║ GROUP_NAME ║
╠════════╬════════════╣
║     44 ║ xex        ║
║     32 ║ tet        ║
╚════════╩════════════╝
```

**actions**

```
╔════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║   STATE    ║
╠════╬════════════╣
║ 44 ║ complete   ║
║ 58 ║ incomplete ║
╚════╩════════════╝
```

Note that `act_id` in table `teams` is also present in table `actions` as `id`

I want to select a table with two columns : `group_id` and `group_name`, where each `group_name` has an `act_id` that has a *complete* `state`.

I'm doing something like :

```
SELECT group_id AND group_name 
FROM clients
WHERE group_name IN (SELECT group_name  
                     FROM teams, actions
                     WHERE teams.act_id = actions.id 
                       AND actions.state IS complete)
```

Is this correct ?

I also thought of something like

```
SELECT group_id AND group_name 
FROM clients
WHERE group_name IN (SELECT group_name 
                     FROM teams
                     WHERE act_id IN (SELECT id 
                                      FROM actions
                                      WHERE teams.act_id = actions.id. 
                                        AND state IS complete))
```

Is either of the above correct?

The table I'm looking to get is obviously this one :

```
╔══════════╦════════════╗
║ GROUP_ID ║ GROUP_NAME ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ abc      ║ xex        ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.* 
FROM    clients a
        INNER JOIN teams b
            ON a.group_name = b.group_name
        INNER JOIN actions c
            ON b.act_ID = c.id
WHERE   c.state = 'complete'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60595/1)

The asterisk `*` you see on the sql query means that it will select all columns in available, in this case, it will all select from table `clients`. If you want to select for specific column only, use `comma` to separate not `AND`. eg,

```
SELECT  a.GROUP_ID, a.GROUP_NAME
FROM    clients a
        INNER JOIN teams b
            ON a.group_name = b.group_name
        INNER JOIN actions c
            ON b.act_ID = c.id
WHERE   c.state = 'complete'
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer JW. The a, b and c that you are using are just random names that you assign to each table so that you can easily identify them and distinguish between them in your query right? Could you also maybe give me the above query using my own more verbose format (without JOINS just by using WHERE, IN, IS, IS NOT, =) so that I can better understand what you are doing? Or is it not possible without JOINs? Thanks once again and I will definitely look at JOINs.

Comment: `a, b, c` are called `ALIAS` (*or nicknames in terms of person name*). There are many possible queries to achieve specific result. The one I like most is by using `JOIN`. This can also be done using `EXISTS`. `;)`